# Using Rails 3.2.13, I'm trying to access Warden Manager before_logout callbacks each time a user sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2.13, I'm trying to access Warden Manager before_logout callbacks each time a user sign out, mainly I want to store login and logout time in my database table which is user_login_logout, I have already store login time in the database table and I also want to store logout time in he same table and same row.

I'm placing this logic in my user model. when I press logout then `Warden::Manager.before_logout` will be call but the problem is that nothing is work except `Time.now`

I want to know why I can't access user_login_logout model in the User model within the Warden::Manager block. I also want to know if my code is wrong then what is the solution, how can I get the logout time and store it in the table.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_login_logouts

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|      

_logout_time = Time.now
 puts _logout_time

_user_role_id = self.user_login_logouts.last.id

if _user_role_id.present?
  UserLoginLogout.update_column(sign_out_at: Time.now)
end

end
```

**Error**

> undefined method user_login_logouts